# Какой общий интерфейс есть у массивов и объектов

Tags: php

Нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает md5 хеш, любого значения стандартного типа, точнее (array, object, int, string);

Написал такую функцию:

```
function getHash($data) : string {
    return md5(is_object($data) || is_array($data) ? serialize($data) : $data);
}
```

Хотелось бы вариант без двух условий, или что-то элегантнее))

Comment: хотя тут объекты могут быть не \Serializable ((

Comment: А ещё в объекте может быть реализована __sleep()

Comment: https://php.net/is_scalar